# Android - Compartilhar Preferências para outro dispositivo

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Minha dúvida é o seguinte: é possível compartilhar informações salvas pelo *SharedPrefences* para outro dispositivo, seja por *bluetooth* ou outra conexão ?

**MainActivity.java:**

```
SharedPreferences.EDITOR editor = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("value1", "example");
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sim", é possível, não tão diretamente como você pode estar pensando.

### 1. Salvar as preferências em algo concreto

Usando o [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) podemos criar um arquivo com dados primitivos para ser posteriormente lido e transformado de volta em um objeto Java. O ponto aqui é pegar todas as preferências e salvar em um Mapa (já que são chaves e valores) utilizando o [SharedPreferences.getAll()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll())

```
File prefsFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "prefs.bak");
if (!prefsFile.exists()) {
    if (!prefsFile.createNewFile())
        // Falha ao criar arquivo
}

try {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(prefsFile));
    output.writeObject(prefs.getAll());
    output.flush();
    output.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Falha ao escrever no arquivo
}
```

### 2. Enviar o prefs.bak ao outro dispositivo

Bem, há várias formas de se fazer isso. Uma vez enviado, tenha conhecimento do caminho do arquivo.

### 3. Ler e aplicar o prefs.bak no outro dispositivo

Supondo que ambos os dispositivos rodam o seu app:

```
File prefsFile = new File("caminho/para/o/prefs.bak");
if (prefsFile.exists()) {
    try {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(prefsFile));
        // Ler o objeto como um mapa
        Map<String, ?> entries = (Map<String, ?>) input.readObject();
        // Na falta de um método "putAll()" vamos dar um loop no mapa e pra cada entry, fazemos um apply()
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : entries.entrySet()) {
            Object o = entry.getValue();
            String key = entry.getKey();

            if (o instanceof Boolean)
                editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) o);
            else if (o instanceof Float)
                editor.putFloat(key, (Float) o);
            else if (o instanceof Integer)
                editor.putInt(key, (Integer) o);
            else if (o instanceof Long)
                 editor.putLong(key, (Long) o);
            else if (o instanceof String)
                 editor.putString(key, ((String) o));
            }
            // Finalmente aplique os novos valores importados
            editor.apply();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException ex) {
         // Falha ao ler arquivo
    }
} else {
    // Arquivo não encontrado
}
```